Low- noise transformer
I've got something that was probably at least once quite valuable and I'm not sure what to do with it. It's a low noise transformer, model 190, made by Princeton Applied Research.
I was clearing out stuff that belonged to my Dad, a physicist who was also a good electronics engineer. He probably used it in one of his experiments. I don't know how old it is - it likely dates from the 70s - or if it would be anything more than a historical curiosity.
I would just list it on ebay, only that (among other reasons) it seems to be a Kafka-esque nightmare where international shipping is involved.
Is it worth going to a lot of trouble over this? Is it something that anybody would actually want?

I’m voting to close this question because we don't sell products on this site

It's still a useful item for people like physicists (often in association with AC bridges and lock-in amplifiers) and not one that wears out (assuming it's not broken now). If you have the equipment (a signal generator and an oscilloscope), test it and add the results
You can list it on eBay if you want, and if you live in the US, restrict it to domestic shipping. If a ferriner orders it eBay will take care of the details and add a handsome fee on top for the service (you would ship it domestically in any case- so check rates and account for very good packing). It should bring a few hundred dollars or more, and if you're not going to use it, maybe someone else will.

...do you mean foreigner? took me a while to work that one out.

@Hearth Yes, indeed.

This signal transformer seems to be quite valuable; there is one unit for sale over at Artisan Technology priced at over $700.  It forms part of the Princeton Applied Research Model 113 low-noise pre-amplifier.
Beware that this is very sensitive to current, for example: do not use a DMM to measure winding resistance, a mere 200uA will magenetise the core and degrade its performance; a de-magnetisation process is then required to restore preformance.

Image above: page III-10, from this document:
https://www.artisantg.com/info/Princeton_Applied_Research_EG_G_190_Datasheet_202081410251.pdf?srsltid=AfmBOopZu5_2Id1OlJjPLPaFNoPIle_CP-rZ5VnFlX0UQGHEtDTlbFwu
